# Force a servlet to return anything from a URL, instead of java.io.IOException?

Tags: servlets

To combat the Same Origin policy I have created a Java Servlet which acts as a proxy server for my AJAX requests to fetch XML's from other locations.

The problem is that any HTTP error responses are not being returned to my client side, instead they are caught as exceptions and logged.

How can I force the servlet the return whatever it finds whether its a 404, 500 etc.

This is an example in my logs

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
```

or
    `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL`:

Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://www.test.com/test.xml";
URL kcim = new URL(url);


        URLConnection kciconn = kcim.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kciconn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        PrintWriter out = kciResponse.getWriter();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //output to client
            out.println(inputLine);

        }

    //close output stream
    System.in.close();
    in.close();
```

So in summary my servlet when it recieves a HTTP error code back ends up breaking itself, resulting in me getting a HTTP 500 Server error from the servlet instead of the true HTTP code from the resource being accessed.

How do I stop it breaking and force the servlet to return whatever it gets back?

Thanks

Comment: So you'd like the client to know the response status code along with the content of the response. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, anything that the servlet receives I want passed onto the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proxy

You are not handling the response status code sent by the target server or processing the headers sent by them, so the client never gets to see them. Using the apache HTTP client you can work around that. The snippet below handles the status code and reads the response headers (but does not set any). You can use that as a template and modify it as you please. The URL `https://github.com/thisurldoesnotexist` does not exist for example, and the response status code is correctly set to `404`. I've assumed the API calls are `GET`s.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://github.com/thisurldoesnotexist");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

    // Echo whatever headers you are interested in.
    Header[] allHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();

    resp.setStatus(statusLine.getStatusCode());
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try
    {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(resp.getWriter());
        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"UTF-8"));
        String temp = null;

        while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(temp);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        resp.setStatus(500);
        // handle the exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if(bufferedWriter != null)
        {
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

## JSONP

While that snippet will fix your problem, I'd suggest you also take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). If your third party provider can wrap the JS in [JSONP it would be a more elegant solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy). I'd write a little more about the benefits of using JSONP, but the article I linked to does a pretty fine job of comparing proxy based solutions and JSONP.

Comment: Thanks, I can't do JSONP as I have no control over the external sources. Plus you cannot do XML with JSONP due to the tags used in both types

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to throw the `JSONP` option out there in case you had not considered it. Cheers.

Comment: Hi , when I deploy this I am getting  "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest"

Comment: You need a maven dependency on `httpclient` from the group `org.apache.httpcomponents`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason Eclipse was not putting my libaries into the servlet "lib" folder. I have to manually place them in using 7zip

Answer (score 1):

1. Use HttpURLConnection instead of URLConnection
2. In your proxy servlet, whether an exception was raised or not, call:

   response.setStatus(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());

Cheers :^)